# How to change the PYTHONPATH of an ipython kernel?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, ipython, data-science

I am doing analysis and I intend to restructure my scripts into a package. I have a directory structure like so:

```
project
|   README.md
|   setup.py
|   requirements.txt
|
└───data
└───notebooks
|     notebook_A.ipynb
|
└───my_package
    |   __init__.py
    |
    └───module_A
    |    __init__.py
    |    source_A.py
    |
    └───module_B
        __init__.py
        source_B.py
```

First I will crete an environment with Conda:

`conda create my_environment`

Then, the goal is to make **my_package** importable in notebooks without loosing the ability to edit the source. So I will run:

```
$ (my_environment) pip install -e .
```

This works as expected and creates:

```
/Applications/anaconda3/envs/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_package.egg-link
```

Then I want to check everything works:

```
$ (my_environment) cd notebooks
```

Everything works in ipython:

```
$ (my_environment) ipython


In [1]: import src
In [2]: src.__path__
Out[2]: ['/Users/jalmarituominen/Desktop/my_environment_project/src']
```

But when I run jupyter notebook and run it with *my_environment* kernel, I get

```
import sys
sys.path
[1]:
['',
'/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python36.zip',
'/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6',
'/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aeosa',
'/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
'/Users/jalmarituominen/.ipython']
```

Obiviously I can't import *my_package* since its not in the PATH.

However, when I change the kernel to *Python 3*, I get:

```
import sys
sys.path
[1]:
['/Applications/anaconda3/envs/my_environment/lib/python36.zip',
'/Applications/anaconda3/envs/my_environment/lib/python3.6',
'/Applications/anaconda3/envs/my_environment/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
'',
'/Applications/anaconda3/envs/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
'/Users/jalmarituominen/Desktop/my_environment_project',
'/Applications/anaconda3/envs/my_environment/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
'/Users/jalmarituominen/.ipython']
```

And *my_package* is importable.

For some reason PATHS of these two environments are mixed up. Any idea how to resolve this? Is it possible to manually change the PATH of a Kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is where I wish Jupyter do something to make changing Environments easy. This is what I did to get corrected results:

```
$ conda activate my_env
$ (my_env) conda install ipykernel -y
$ (my_env) python -m ipykernel install --user --name my_env --display-name "My Env"
```

I then made sure that I have correct Python path to my env

```
$ (my_env) jupyter kernelspec list | grep my_env
```

This gave me the location of my environmental kernel. In it there is a .json setting file that you can edit the path to correct Python, display name, and other things.

After this I could toggle between kernels.

Comment: Here's how the edited kernel.json looks like:
```json
{
 "argv": [...],
 "display_name": "...",
 "language": "...",
 "env": {
     "PYTHONPATH": "/path/to/your/local/package"
 }
}
```

Comment: conda will generate the file automatically. If there is a name and path to the correct environment, deactivate the environment. Activate environment with Jupyter Lab|Notebook and you should be able to switch Python kernel. I am not sure how it is done in iPython

Comment: Yes, conda will generate this file, but without the "env" entry (at least in my case, I guess because my default PYTHONPATH is none). It took me a little googling to figure out how to add the "PYTHONPATH" entry into this json file, so I thought it is worthwhile to share it here.